# delayed login to Windows SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

Last week I had a problem with my server (Windows SBS 2008 ), so I made a restore point to resolve that problem. But after I did it any workstation (Windows 7) try to login takes 50 seconds. I tried to find an error in event viewer, but there are no errors.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the event viewer on both the workstations and the server?  Are you sure there is nothing relevant in either?

Comment: Here is an excellent blog post by Mark Russinovich on how to troubleshot slow logins: http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx

Comment: Do those workstations log in fast on cached credentials, by disconnecting the ethernet cable before login? If so, you most probably are experiencing AD and/or DNS related issues.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is often down to the client not being able to communicate with the domain controller, usually because the clients primary DNS server is not set to the IP of the SBS server.